# Ubuntu 17.10.1 crashing after clean install

Tags: google-chrome, crash

This is the screenshot after it crashes:

[image: This is the screenshot after it crashes]

Ubuntu boots normally but this happened after I opened Google Chrome. It will hang for a minute and then, this black screen.

If I press Ctrl+Alt+Del it will reboot normally and ubuntu offers to send a report.

Any idea what could it be? Of course I'm a newbie but I would appreciate some help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why not send a report?

Comment: Sent the report to Ubuntu, where can I find the log file to post it here?

Comment: Please don't post bug reports as questions here. Bug reports are off topic in this site.

Comment: I have the same situation. But not after install. A few days ago my chrome based applications (atom, slack, chrome) started to constantly crash. BTW, I think it is ok to ask such questions here, may be someone will give some hints how to solve this by some config.